# onClick ruby, wrong issue with " not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick "

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm doing an interface with ruby, I would like to add a dynamic input. 
So here is the code that I've done, but I still have an error :

My view :

```
<%= form_for(@progformation, url: "/prog_formation/new") do |f| %>
    <div id="Objectifs">
    <h3>Objectifs</h3>
        <%= f.text_field :objectif, autofocus: true,:placeholder=> "Objectifs",:class => "form-control"  %>
        <%= f.text_field :objectif, autofocus: true,:placeholder=> 
    "Objectifs",:class => "form-control"  %>
        <input type="button" value="Ajouter un nouvel obj" onClick="addInput('Objectifs')">
        </div>
        <script>
        function addInput("divName")
        {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML ='<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="prog_formation_objectifs_attributes_' + (counter + 1) +'_mot">Mot ' + (counter + 1) +'</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="prog_formation_objectifs_attributes_' + (counter + 1) +'_mot" name="prog_formation[objectifs_attributes][' + (counter + 1) +'][mot]" type="text" /></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="prog_formation_objectifs_attributes_' + (counter + 1) +'_definition">Definition ' + (counter + 1) +'</label><div class="col-sm-10"><textarea class="form-control" id="prog_formation_objectifs_attributes_' + (counter + 1) +'_definition" name="prog_formation[objectifs_attributes][' + (counter + 1) +'][definition]" row="3"></textarea></div></div>';
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  counter++; }
</script>
<% end %>
```

My 2 models :

```
class ProgFormation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :formation
    belongs_to :users
    has_many :objectifs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :objectifs
    validates :point_princip, presence: {
        message: "Veuillez indiqué les points de votre formation"
    }
end
```

and

```
class Objectif < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :formation
end
```

but I always get the same error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addInput is not defined
>           at HTMLInputElement.onclick (new:59)
>       onclick @ new:59

I actually don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 0):

[FIXED] it was all about the " arround divName